# Table columns name does not update on model change

Tags: sapui5

I create a table:

```
oTable.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData));
        oTable.bindAggregation("items", "/items", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells: oData.cols.map(function (colname) {
                return new sap.m.Label({ text: "{" + colname + "}" });
            })
        }));
```

Then I want to change the model (it contain rows AND cols):

```
oTable.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(NEWoData));
    model =oTable.getModel();
    model.refresh();
```

But after refresh I see the new data(:D) but the old cols name!

Comment: You see the old column names since you didn't change the cell aggregation to use the new model; it still links to oData.cols.map ;-)

Comment: thankyou! How i can change the links?
I resolved deleting the model

`oTable.getModel().destroy();
oTable.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData));`

But i don't like it...

Comment: Don't use a reference to `oData.cols` but to your table model `oTable.getModel().getProperty("cols")`, assuming your model has a property 'cols'

Comment: `cells: oTable.getModel().getProperty("cols").map(function (colname) {
    return new sap.m.Label({ text: "{" + colname + "}" });
   })`

not work :/

Comment: Make sure you have set the path to 'cols' correct, it should match your model structure (if it's in the root of your model, use '/cols'). Can you post a JSBin sample?

Comment: ok, this is my code: http://pastebin.com/KmjBQ7Yv

It work for items but the bind with colus is at oTable creating time...

Comment: Your can't set a model to your table prior to initializing your table. You'd better first create your table, then set its model, then bind rows and columns. See http://jsbin.com/qaqur/1/edit for an example

Comment: I use `sap.m.Table.Table`, not `sap.ui.table.Table`.
I have only `.bindItems`, not `.bindRows` and `.bindColumns`

Comment: ...Your solution not work. I try to retrieve from model and not from oData but when i change the model i see ongli the new rows but the old cols name...
http://pastebin.com/mgWkenXD

Comment: My bad, didn't notice you are using m.table instead of commons.table... Not sure why it won't refresh your data though. Did you try a table invalidate? https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#invalidate I'm not that familiar with the m.table, maybe someone else can give some hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding the cells of the ColumnListItem to "/cols"